# Bounding summations

Tags: analysis, algorithms

Show that $\sum k2^k = \Theta( k2^k)$.

I tried to use mathematical induction to prove the bound, but it didn't work. 
There are other ways that can be used to prove this bound, like bounding the terms, splitting summations etc.. but I can't seem to find a valid proof.

$f(n)= \Theta(g(n))$ iff $f$ is bounded both above and below by $g$ asymptotically, i.e.
$k_1 g(n)\leqslant f(n)\leqslant k_2g(n)$, for some positive $k_1$, $k_2$.

Comment: Are we to assume you mean $\sum_{k=1}^n k\;2^k =\Theta(n\;2^n)$ ?

Comment: Yes, my bad. @ConradTurner

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function:$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n x^k=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}
$$
Then:
$$f'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n kx^{k-1}=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{k=1}^n kx^{k}=\frac{{x}^{n}\,\left( n\,x-n-1\right) +1}{{x}^{2}-2\,x+1}
$$

So:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n kx^{k}=\frac{{x}^{n+1}\,\left( n\,x-n-1\right) +x}{{x}^{2}-2\,x+1}
$$

(you could obtain something equivalent to the above just by asking Wolfram Alpha, or equivalent, to sum that finite series)

Now substiture $2$ for $x$ and you should be able to take it from there...

Comment: In your initial statement you used the geometric series for summation formula from $k = 0$, but here we sum from $k=1$ onwards, hence it should read: $$ \sum_{k=1}^n x^k = \frac{x^{n+1}-x}{x-1} $$ but as they both have the same derivative everything else is correct.